# How do I use beautiful soup to format a REST URL data pull into a python data frame?

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access U.S. Drought monitor data through their REST service. Below is an example url that gets me some data I need

```
url = "https://usdmdataservices.unl.edu/api/HUCStatistics/GetDroughtSeverityStatisticsByArea?aoi=10190016&startdate=1/1/2022&enddate=12/31/2022&statisticsType=2"
```

How do I read this into python and create a pandas data frame?

This is what I have so far but I'm getting a really long string with beautifulsoup and think I must be doing something wrong.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
text = soup.get_text()[2:-2]
```

I'm expecting a pandas data frame that looks like:

| index | HUCId | MapDate | HUC | HUCLevel | None | D0 | D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | ValidStart | ValidEnd | StatisticFormatID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10190016 | 20221227 | Lower Lodgepole | 8 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 1,334.13 | 0.00 | 2022-12-27 | 2023-01-02 | 2 |

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need BeautifulSoup for this. Try it this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = json.loads(page.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

The output should be your expected table.

Answer (score 0):

With [`read_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) you could read the JSON directly into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 

pd.read_json('https://usdmdataservices.unl.edu/api/HUCStatistics/GetDroughtSeverityStatisticsByArea?aoi=10190016&startdate=1/1/2022&enddate=12/31/2022&statisticsType=2')
```

###### Output

|  | HUCId | MapDate | HUC | HUCLevel | None | D0 | D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | ValidStart | ValidEnd | StatisticFormatID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10190016 | 20221227 | Lower Lodgepole | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.00 | 1,334.13 | 0 | 2022-12-27 | 2023-01-02 | 2 |
| 1 | 10190016 | 20221220 | Lower Lodgepole | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.00 | 1,334.13 | 0 | 2022-12-20 | 2022-12-26 | 2 |
| 2 | 10190016 | 20221213 | Lower Lodgepole | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.00 | 1,303.68 | 30.46 | 2022-12-13 | 2022-12-19 | 2 |
| 3 | 10190016 | 20221206 | Lower Lodgepole | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.00 | 1,303.68 | 30.46 | 2022-12-06 | 2022-12-12 | 2 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 49 | 10190016 | 20220118 | Lower Lodgepole | 8 | 0 | 0 | 307.93 | 1,026.21 | 0.00 | 0 | 2022-01-18 | 2022-01-24 | 2 |
| 50 | 10190016 | 20220111 | Lower Lodgepole | 8 | 0 | 0 | 307.93 | 890.97 | 135.24 | 0 | 2022-01-11 | 2022-01-17 | 2 |
| 51 | 10190016 | 20220104 | Lower Lodgepole | 8 | 0 | 0 | 306.75 | 892.14 | 135.24 | 0 | 2022-01-04 | 2022-01-10 | 2 |
| 52 | 10190016 | 20211228 | Lower Lodgepole | 8 | 0 | 0 | 306.75 | 892.14 | 135.24 | 0 | 2021-12-28 | 2022-01-03 | 2 |